# JQuery - hide() and addClass conflict

Tags: jquery, hide, addclass, dynamic-allocation

I am encountering a problem assigning classes and hidding and showing `td`'s.
Here is my HTML:

```
<table id="fundTable">
    <tr> 
         <td class="rentability"> <span class="someClass"> 0.12 </span> </td>
         <td class="absoluteResult">0.66</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
         <td class="rentability"> <span class="someClass"> -0.24  </span> </td>
         <td class="absoluteResult">-.45</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my Javascript (onchange):

```
$('#fundTable tr').each(function() {
    formatedAbsoluteResult = 'SOME NUMBER'
    $(this).find('td[class=absoluteResult]').fadeOut(100).html(formatedAbsoluteResult).fadeIn(100)
    if (formatedAbsoluteResult < 0)
        $(this).find('td[class=absoluteResult]').removeClass('green').addClass('red')
    else 
        $(this).find('td[class=absoluteResult]').removeClass('red').addClass('green')
}
```

The idea is to display the number in green if it is positive, by assigning the appropriate class. In red otherwise. This code works perfectly when I run it once on page load. Then, the `td`'s that have an assigned class (either `red` or `green`) are not updated anymore (onchange), whereas the others are on:

```
$(this).find('td[class=absoluteResult]').fadeOut(100).html(formatedAbsoluteResult).fadeIn(100)
```

I do not understand this behaviour. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by "onchange"? the onchange event only applies to field elements ie:input,select,textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a slight adjustment of your overall design of this block will help.

This seems to do what you are trying to accomplish ([live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YdteC/1)). Don't forget to change the parts where I improvised:

```
    $("#testing").keyup(function() {
    $("#fundTable tr").each(function() {
       formattedAbsoluteResult = 
        $(this).find("td.absoluteResult").fadeOut(100, function () {
            if (formattedAbsoluteResult < 0)
            {
                $("#fundTable tr").find("td.absoluteResult").removeClass("green").addClass("red");
            }
            else
            {
                $("#fundTable tr").find("td.absoluteResult").removeClass("red").addClass("green");
            }
        }).html(formattedAbsoluteResult).fadeIn(100);
    });
});
```

Notice the callback function used, also "keyup" instead of "onchange", but you can use whatever you need. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I applied your modifications step by step, and actually end up solving the problem by only replacing all the **td[class=someClass]** by **td.someClass** and now it is working perfectly fine. 

Do you have any idea why I got this behaviour ?

Thanks a lot anyway, as stupid as it seems, I did not think of trying such changes :)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but the dot notation for classes is just shorter so I used it. My only guess at the moment would be browser compatibility or jQuery version differences? Well anyway, glad you got it working!